# ERROR: permission denied for relation event

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am new in Postgres and I have the following problem:

I want to add some data on database with the following way:

```
INSERT INTO event (eventid)
VALUES ('1');
```

where event is a table. But I receive the following message

> permission denied for relation event

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What access do you have to the table? You may only have SELECT access (meaning you can only query the table, not input new data)

Comment: Use `psql` to get the following information: `SELECT current_user;` - `\du <username>` (where `<username>` is the result of the previous query) - `\z event`. Then add the results to the question.